# Can't insert image into db sqLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap, android-sqlite

**Saving Bitmap into database:**

```
Bitmap photo = value.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
    if (photo != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        bArray = bos.toByteArray();
    }

  // photo_imi.setImageBitmap(photo);
    //textview1.setText("Your name is: " + user_name + " AND Your email is " + user_email);
    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyDataBas", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_INFO (name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, imageCol BLOB);");
    //ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    //cv.put("name", user_name);
    //cv.put("email", user_email);
    //cv.put("img", bArray);

    //db.insert("USER_INFO", null, cv);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO USER_INFO ('name','email','imageCol')VALUES('"+user_name+"','"+user_email+"','"+bArray+"');");
```

**Retrieving blob and converting into bitmap then showing it in ImageView:**

```
String query="SELECT * FROM USER_INFO WHERE TRIM(name) = '" + user_name.trim() +"'";
        Cursor detail= db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(detail!=null){
        detail.moveToFirst();
        do{
            img=detail.getBlob(2);
            s_email=detail.getString(detail.getColumnIndex("email"));

            fimg= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
        }while(detail.moveToNext());
    }
    show_email=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_email);
    show_email.setText("Email:" + s_email);

    fetch_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fetch_image);


        fetch_image.setImageBitmap(fimg);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Retrive successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method :

```
public void InsertToDB( String name, String email, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put("name",    name);
    cv.put("email",    email);
    cv.put("imageCol", image);
    database.insert("USER_INFO ", null, cv);
}
```